# Multitrack Studio how to loop a section

Tags: software, daw

I have multitrack Studio Standard. How to I replay a section of the tracks over and over for practice?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the manual.  Instructions on how to set up a loop are on page 107.

http://www.multitrackstudio.com/files/manual.pdf

In particular:

[image]